# macOS Calendar app stopped syncing with Google Calendar

Tags: macos, high-sierra, calendar, google-calendar

My Google Calendar account has stopped syncing with the Apple Calendar app on macOS (High Sierra 10.13.4). I've tried turning Google Calendar off and back on in the System Preferences -> Internet Accounts panel and i've tried removing the account from the Calendar app. Neither have made any difference. I don't see anything unusual in the system logs.

Everything is up to date in the Google Calendar web app.

Anyone else have this problem, or creative solutions? Are there more advanced things i can do to force a reset on the syncing of these calendars, like command line settings or Library file deletions?

Answer (score 9):

Deleting the Calendar cache and rebooting my Mac seemed to solve it, at least for now. I followed these instructions:

https://wilkinsit.ca/mac-osx/clear-calendar-cache-mac-os/

1. Backup Calendar from the `File > Export > Calendar Archive…` menu option.
2. Close Calendar.app
3. Navigate to `Library > Calendar` folder in Finder
4. Remove all files that start with `Calendar Cache`
5. Reboot
6. Open Calendar.app and watch as it initializes calendars

Comment: After restarting the app a few times, deleting caches and disabling/re-enabling Google Calendar syncing, it worked even without a reboot. Thank you!

Comment: Did the trick even without reboot!